# Gmail API in python and Gmail App giving different messageId for same message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

So watch a tutorial on internet i created a Google App Script(GAS) for getting History id. using previous history ids i created a script which gives message id and thread id for every incoming requests and posts it on my API in function postReq(). Now when i try to use these ids in python gmail api they show error that they dont exist. I tried to get ids for certain messages and found out they are different from those given from GAS. Is this something api does or i can fix this anyway? Thanks

```
function doPost(e) {
  let message = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString()).message
  let data = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(message.data)).getDataAsString();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...')
  let doc  = DocumentApp.openById('...').getBody()
  let para = doc.getParagraphs()[0]
  let prevId = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0][0];
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  let historyId = parseInt(data.historyId)
  let history = Gmail.Users.History.list("nyxgodxd@gmail.com",{"startHistoryId": `${prevId}` }).history
  let threadId = history[0].messages[0].threadId
  let msgId = history[0].messages[0].id
  let msg = Gmail.Users.Messages.get(userId = 'me', id = `${msgId}`).snippet
  let res = {historyId,threadId, msgId,msg}
  para.appendText(`\n${JSON.stringify(res)}\n`)
  postReq(res)
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues([[`${historyId}`]])
  return 200;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Please see[how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)